# There is a way to set a radio button as a number type instead a string?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using material.angular.io.
I would like know if there is way to set a Radio Button as a number type instead a string type.

Is it that i'm using: https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview

Answer (score 1):

I reached it yet!!
I need just set a default value number on my controller, for example:

```
public defaultValue = 10;
```

And on html set this model

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Record Calls" [(ngModel)]="defaultValue">
```

And it will be handled as a number.

Comment: use [value]="variable" or [value]="3" (not simple value="...)

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Record Calls" value = "your number">
```

Comment: Hi, please expand on your answer as to why this would be a solution to OP's issue. This will help OP and future visitors of the site. Thanks!